# Terminal Mathias’s dotfiles .functions

Tags: terminal, dotfiles

I recently [got Mathias’s dotfiles](http://mths.be/dotfiles) on my terminal, and I mainly have two questions about this repo.

*First:* I can't make my custom aliases / functions get to work. I writing them in the default location of Mathias’s dotfiles, in `.aliases` / `.functions`. I do reload `.bash_profile` after I added and saved the code.

*Second:* How can I keep up to date with updates automatically while in the meanwhile I have custom aliases and functions setup in `.aliases / .functions` at the default location of Mathias’s repo. ( `/Users/TheSpiritMolecule/dotfiles` )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Glad to hear you like [my dotfiles](http://mths.be/dotfiles) :)

> *First:* I can't make my custom aliases / functions get to work. I writing them in the default location of Mathias’s dotfiles, in `.aliases` / `.functions`. I do reload `.bash_profile` after I added and saved the code.

What have you tried? Please describe in detail what you did exactly: which files you edited, which aliases/functions you added. Are you sure you’re editing the `~/.aliases` and `~/.functions` and not the files in the repository?

> *Second:* How can I keep up to date with updates automatically while in the meanwhile I have custom aliases and functions setup in `.aliases / .functions` at the default location of Mathias’s repo. ( `/Users/TheSpiritMolecule/dotfiles` )

The idea is that you don’t use my dotfiles directly, but rather create your own fork of my repository. That way, you can always merge any changes that I made, and that you like, back into your fork through the magic that is Git.

If for some reason you really don’t want to create a fork, you can [still add custom aliases and functions](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles#add-custom-commands-without-creating-a-new-fork) by creating an `~/.extra` file. That file will never be part of the repository so it won’t cause any merge conflicts, but my dotfiles will source it if such a file exists, along with the other files. You can use this to add a few custom commands without the need to fork this entire repository, or to add commands you don’t want to commit to a public repository.

My `~/.extra` looks something like this:

```
# Git credentials
# Not in the repository, to prevent people from accidentally committing under my name
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Mathias Bynens"
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
git config --global user.name "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="mathias@mailinator.com"
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
git config --global user.email "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
```

You could also use `~/.extra` to override settings, functions and aliases from my dotfiles repository. It’s probably better to [fork this repository](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/fork) instead, though.

Comment: Hello @Mathias , is there a way to uninstall / remove dotfiles and revert to original Mac OS settings?

Comment: @Eray https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205122/removing-mathias-dotfiles-settings